# IBM db2 connection gets closed after some time

Tags: python, db2

I'm trying to connect to db2 (ibm_db). The connection is successful, i'm able to make changes in the db. But after a while the connection gets closed. I'm not closing the connection anywhere.

It throws this errror:

**[IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0106E  Connection is closed. SQLSTATE=08003 SQLCODE=-99999**
2019-04-11 03:11:20,558 - INFO - werkzeug - 9.46.72.43 - - [11/Apr/2019 03:11:20] POST  200

Here is my code: (Not exact. But something similar)

```py
import ibm_db
conn = ibm_db.connect("database","username","password")

def update():
    stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, "UPDATE employee SET bonus = '1000' WHERE job = 'MANAGER'")
```

How do i maintain the connection the whole time. I mean whenever the service is running.

Comment: What type of connection is it? Is Db2 remote or on the same host? How long is "after a while", seconds, minutes or hours?

Comment: It is a db2 remote connection. It closes like after 20 mins.

Comment: Is it disconnecting in the middle of the statement or are you running multiple, separate statements and it disconnects between the statements?

Comment: So, i run this service on a server, the connection is initialised only while starting the service. It keeps on running. I hit the service, it runs, executes the update command in sql, after like 15 to 20 mins, i hit the service again, then it raises that execption. Basically i'm calling that update() function everytime i hit the service, it runs for the first 5 mins, after that the connection gets close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your design of only making a connection when the service starts is unsuitable for long running services.

There's nothing you can do to stop the other end (i.e. the Db2-server, or any intervening gateway) from closing the connection. The connection can get closed for a variety of reasons. For example, the Db2-server may be configured to discard idle sessions, or sessions that break some site-specific workload-management rules. Network issues can cause connections to become unavailable. Service-management matters can cause connections to be forced off etc.

Check out the pconnect method to see if it helps you. Otherwise consider a better design such as connection-pooling, reconnect-on-demand etc.